# What are the default Jsonb serialization format for java date objects

Tags: java, date, jsonb

What are the date/time formats jsonb uses by default for the various date objects of the java apis?

For instance, javascript's `new Date().toJSON()` produces output containing second fractions I was expecting to parse using Jsonb to a `ZonedDateTime` field, but second fractions are not supported by the default serializer.

Do I have to specify a custom format to map javascript `Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jsonb spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pr/jsr367/index.html) specifies the default mapping implementations should support in section 3.5 Date:

> Implementations MUST support binding of the following standard Java date/time classes:
>
> - java.util.Date
> - java.util.Calendar
> - java.util.GregorianCalendar
> - java.util.TimeZone
> - java.util.SimpleTimeZone
> - java.time.Instant
> - java.time.Duration
> - java.time.Period
> - java.time.LocalDate
> - java.time.LocalTime
> - java.time.LocalDateTime
> - java.time.ZonedDateTime
> - java.time.ZoneId
> - java.time.ZoneOffset
> - java.time.OffsetDateTime
> - java.time.OffsetTime

A [javaindeed article](https://www.javaindeed.com/getting-started-with-json-b/) lists the various formatters used for them along with example output:

```
{
  "date":               "2016-07-27T23:07:41",
  "calendar":           "2016-07-27T23:07:41.782+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]",
  "gregorianCalendar":  "2016-07-27T23:07:41.801+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]",
  "timeZone":           "Europe/Copenhagen",
  "simpleTimeZone":     "Europe/Paris",
  "instant":            "2016-07-27T21:07:41.806Z",
  "duration":           "PT96H",
  "period":             "P3M",
  "localDate":          "2016-07-27",
  "localTime":          "23:07:41.807",
  "localDateTime":      "2016-07-27T23:07:41.807",
  "zonedDateTime":      "2016-07-27T23:07:41.807+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]",
  "zoneId":             "Europe/Copenhagen",
  "zoneOffset":         "+03:30",
  "offsetDateTime":     "2016-07-27T23:07:41.807+02:00",
  "offsetTime":         "23:07:41.807+02:00",
}
```

In my case, a `java.time.Instant` instance would be deserialized correctly from javascript's `Date.toJSON()` output string.